# Generate java code from WSDL when HTTP authentication is enabled

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wsdl, http-authentication

I have custom **wsdl url**. Now in Intelij I am trying to generate java classes using this **wsdl**. I tried to use **`Tools->WebServices->Generate Java Code From Wsdl`. When **http-auth** is disabled on my wsdl url, this option `Apache axis 2` works good, But it's required that http-auth to be enabled. There is no option under Axis 2 to enter username and password. I've also tried `Apache axis` option. I entered user/password after that **ok** button enabled but after clicking on it  I got an error: **Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: mywsdlurl**. There is also **Glassfix/Jax-WS 2.2 RI /Metro 1.X / JWSDP 2.2** option which worked fine before enabling http-auth. Can someone suggest correct way how to generate Java code from WSDL when http authentication is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set up proxy (like [tinyProxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/)) that adds [authroziation header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) to the requests with proper credentials encoded and configure your IDE to work throughout that proxy.

Answer (score 0):

After trying 3 hours I found this solution. I created file **someFile.txt** with the content **http://user:pass@host:port/ws/mywsdl.wsdl**. And then in the same directory opened cmd and executed command:

```
wsimport -Xauthfile "someFile.txt" -keep -p com.demo.my_package_name "http://host:port/ws/mywsdl.wsdl"
```

And then generated package/classes copied into my project.

Take into account that you have to add C:\Program Files\Java\java_version\bin into your EnvironmentVariables->path section. Otherwise wsimport won't work.

Hope this helps to someone.